Custom tabbar in VisionOS
How can I achieve a tab bar with a custom non-transparent background color to the bar and custom icons similar to this one in the vision OS Disney+ app?custom tab bar
I have tried adding the extra button as an ornament but not getting the desired result.
Adding offsets to the button if added as a tab item also produce no good result.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can make a basic tab view like this:
TabView {
Text("List")
    .tabItem {
        Label("List", systemImage: "checklist")
            .glassBackgroundEffect(displayMode: .never)
    }

Text("Favorites")
    .tabItem {
        Label("Favorites", systemImage: "star")
        .background(Color.black)
    }
}
.padding()

I'm unsure what you mean by "custom" but if you are referring to the fact that that Disney+ tab bar uses custom icons, you can use "image" instead of "system image".
If you are referring to the custom background color and segmentation, I would recommend using ornaments instead of a TabView. Here's an example of a segmented ornament with a custom color. (Individual buttons can also have custom colors but I did not use that here)
    .ornament(attachmentAnchor: .scene(.leading)) {
    VStack {
        Button {
            
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "book")
        }
        Spacer()
        Button {
            
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "gear")
        }
    }
    .padding()
    .background(Color.blue)
    .cornerRadius(30)
    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 20, trailing: 150))
    VStack {
        Button {
            
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "book")
        }
    }
    .padding()
    .background(Color.blue)
    .cornerRadius(30)
    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 150))
}


Hi. I tried combining a tab view with an ornament but it wouldn't appear as your suggestion. That example you are sending works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!

Glad it works! This solution is supposed to be instead of a tab view and can't be used in combination with it. To make it functional, you can add an enum or switch variable in the view for the selected tab and have the buttons change the variable and the view change depending on the case of the variable.
If you want to use Tab View, you have to use the generic tab bar.
